# Cannot print NOP ('\x90') in terminal

Tags: c, gdb, printf, no-op

I have a C program that writes a NOP character to stdout:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(char *argc, char *argv[]) {

    fwrite("\x90", 1, sizeof(char), stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

I also have another program that takes input, which i am runnning in gdb (so i can view the stack).

After running the first program i copy the NOP from stdout and paste it in GDB as input for the second program.

When viewing the stack i always get this value:

```
0x00bdbfef
```

When it should be

```
0x00000090
```

Why is this? The problem also seems to occur with python but i cannot pinpoint why.

Comment: How do you *copy the NOP from stdout and paste it*?

Comment: Aside: int main( **int** argc, char *argv[])

Comment: @Pablo I highlight the character printed to my terminal with my house and right click and click 'copy', then i right click and click 'paste'

Comment: I don't think that NOP (which coding is that, that is beyond ascii) is a printable character so you terminal emulator might replace it with other printable characters and that's what you are copying, see paxdiablo's answer. What you should do, is execute `./your_first_program | gdb ./your_second_program` and then read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utf-8 sequence `ef bf bd` (keeping in mind the byte reversal of larger data types in some architectures) is the replacement-character code point, the diamond with a question mark within.

Most likely your terminal is unable to render `90` so it gives you that instead. And, when you mark and copy that character elsewhere, that's what it is.

Comment: how could i fix this issue?